# bouillon vs stock vs broth

Tags: difference

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/bouillon):
bouillon - [count, noncount] a clear liquid in which meat, chicken, fish, or vegetables have been cooked and which is eaten as soup or used to make sauces:
*beef bouillon*

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/stock):
stock - [noncount] liquid in which meat, fish, or vegetables have been cooked and then removed and which is used to make soups, sauces, etc.:
*The recipe calls for one cup of chicken/beef stock*.

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/broth):
broth - [count, noncount] liquid in which food (such as meat) has been cooked:
*chicken broth*

Based on these definitions, I can't understand the difference between the three.

What is the difference between "bouillon", "stock" and "broth"?

Comment: Are you interested in a detailed answer, as a professional cook.  Or just the generic sense as non-experts understand it.

Comment: @JamesK I will be glad of any opinion from native English speakers.

Comment: It probably depends where you come from.  In the UK "bouillon" is a word mostly used by chefs. It's really a French loanword, but it means the same as "stock". Ordinary people (who are not chefs) just call it "stock". "Broth" can mean the same, but it can also be used for a specific kind of soup, with vegetables and/or meat, plus a thin/clear stock base.

Comment: Personally, in Canada, I also be prefer to use "bouillon" for cubes, "stock" for powder, and "broth" for liquid, according to the names the products tend to have in the store -- even though I know the first two are really just reductions of the same liquid that properly bears all three names.

Comment: In the US, *bouillon* is only used for cubes, and I don't think most people could tell you the difference between *stock* and *broth*.

Comment: I just noticed this discussion from M-W online, which may be of interest: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/broth-or-stock-a-difference-you-can-taste

Answer (score 12):

There is little difference for most people. They are all savoury liquids used in cooking.

In terms of *use*, a broth is the liquid in a simple soup. When you have the soup you drink the broth. However such soups are not so popular nowadays.

A stock might be used, for example when making risotto, or when making a stew.  You don't drink the stock, because it is absorbed by the other ingredients. Most stocks are not drunk directly.

And this is the main difference.  A broth is a light savoury liquid that may be drunk as is, or made into a light soup. A stock is a savoury flavoured liquid that is used as a base for other dishes.

Bouillon is just the French word for broth. A bouillon, in the English kitchen, is a dehydrated stock or broth, it may be bought in the form of cubes or powder.

There are technical differences.

Some consider that stock is made by simmering bones, whereas a broth is made by simmering meat. Of course there also vegetarian stocks, broths and bouillon that have neither meat nor bones.

Comment: Just waiting for the soup nerds to arrive to tell me that this is all wrong

Comment: The soup nerds are all on the cooking stack. If this question were posted there you’d probably get a lot more drama ;-)

Comment: @ToddWilcox [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/stock-vs-broth-whats-the-difference-in-usage/4597) and another [similar question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2960/use-any-part-of-an-animal-for-making-stock-broth/2970) have been answered there already indeed. One key difference is whether it's salted or not - as I understand it, stocks are customarily not salted, as the salt is added when preparing the actual dish. Also sounds like there's possibly some difference in whether it's bones or meat + bones

Comment: This seems fairly accurate, but there are a lot of subtleties. The term "broth" is often used for the liquid you cook oriental noodles in, but AFAIK wouldn't be used for the liquid you cook a stew in (Wikipedia suggests a stew is cooked in gravy, or at least contains gravy when served).

Comment: Well, "gravy" is another savoury liquid in cooking.  You might use a stock as the base for a gravy.

Comment: "whereas a broth is made by simmering meat" - it's probably more often meat and bones.  So, stock = just bones; broth = not just bones.  But the main point, that it's not worth worrying about the differences, is correct.  Especially now that we've (at least in the US) got [*bone broth*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bone+broth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).  Only the most delusional soup nazi would still try to argue that *bone broth* is just *stock*.  That ship has sailed - on a powerful tailwind of marketing hot air.

Comment: @Juhasz I actually do see many articles on Google stating that bone broth is actually a stock, while others invent various differences in order to try and distinguish the two.

Comment: They're here...